# How did Cohen-Tannoudji (QM) manipulated this?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, fourier-transform, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, dispersion

In the first chapter of Cohen-Tannoudji’s Quantum Mechanics Book, there's this part of the chapter called "Time evolution of a free wave-packet". So one starts with the wave packet given by

$$\psi(x,0)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int g(k)e^{ikx}dx\tag{I.C-8}$$
where $g(k)$ is the Fourier transform of $\psi(x,0)$. So one assume
$$g(k)=|g(k)|e^{i\alpha(k)}.\tag{I.C-12}$$

This way, if $\alpha(k)$ varies within the interval $$[k_0-\frac{\Delta k}{2},k_0+\frac{\Delta k}{2}]\tag{p.25}.$$ Then, if $\Delta k$ is sufficiently small, we can expand it like $$\alpha(k)=\alpha(k_0)+(k-k_0)\left[\frac{d\alpha}{dk}\right]_{k=k_0}.\tag{I.C-13}$$

Okay, all of this is okay to me. Now comes what I didn't get. With some manipulation of the integral he gets to: $$\psi(x,0)\approx\frac{e^{i[k_0x+\alpha(k_0)]}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int |g(k)|e^{i(k-k_0)(x-x_0)}dk\tag{I.C-14}$$ where $$\left[\frac{d\alpha}{dk}\right]_{k=k_0}=-x_0.\tag{I.C-15}$$

So my questions are: how do I get to the last integral? Because I tried so many time and didn't get there only by replacing $\alpha(k)$ for its approximation. Another question is: why can I set the derivative of alpha as $x_0$?

Comment: You seem to be missing an $i$ in the exponent of your equation I.C-14.

Comment: Regarding your question, you already have the $ix_0(k-k_0)$ and the $ixk$ in the exponent (after plugging in the expansion). So, just add zero to the term in the exponent like: $0=ik_0 x - i k_0 x$ and then factor out the $e^{i k_0 x}$ and take it outside the integral, since it doesn't depend on $k$.

Comment: hint: note the qualifier **appreciable** in the original text: "Assume that $\alpha(k)$ varies sufficiently smoothly within the interval $[k_0 -\Delta k/2, k_0+\Delta k/2]$ where $|g(k)|$ is appreciable"